# Question in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Given the letters a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h how many words of 8 letters can you form, you can't use the same letter twice and the word shouldn't start with the letters a,b.

I tried to do this:

I said that the first letter we have 6 options, then took the rest of the word like a line so there are 7! options for the rest of the 7 letters, so i got $6\cdot 7!= 30240$ **but according to the book** the right answer is 19440.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks to me like you are correct and the book is wrong.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Are you sure you have described the question accurately?  I suggest reprinting it exactly as it appears, with no alterations or edits,